# In how many ways can points be assigned to five questions with one to four points per question so that the total is $14$?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

A professor must write an exam with $5$ questions. Question number i should give $p_i \in \mathbb{Z}$ points. The sum of the points must be $14$ and each question must give at least $1$ point and a maximum of $4$ points. In how many ways can he distribute the points on the questions?

I first turned $p_i= x_i - 1$ so I can get $0 \le x_i \le 3$ instead. Then I put the variable $x_i$ in the equation and got $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 = 9$. The total amount of combination is $C(tot) = C(5+9-1, 9)= C(13, 4)$. What I then did was find how many combinations there are when one $x$ can be greater than $3$, and then when $2$ can be greater than $3$. $C_1 = C(9,4)C(5,1)$ and $C_2 = C(5,4)C(5,2)$. So the answer is $C(13,4) - C(9,4)C(5,1) - C(5,4) C(5,2)$

What my answer sheet says is, $C = C(13,4) - C(9,4)C(5,1) + C(5,4) C(5,2) = 715-630+50= 135$ What I answered was $715 - 105 - 50 = 560$ How is $C(9,4)C(5,1)= 630$? Besides why did they do $+50$ instead of $-50$??
Can anyone help me ?

Comment: Hint : Inclusion-Exclusion. Also, $C(9,4)C(5,1)$ is indeed 630.

Answer (score 1):

If $p_i$ points are assigned to the $i$th question, with each $p_i$ a positive integer satisfying $1 \leq p_i \leq 4$, and the examination has a total of $14$ points, $1 \le i \le 5$, then
$$p_1 + p_2 + p_3 + p_4 + p_5 = 14 \tag{1}$$
is an equation in the positive integers subject to the restrictions $p_i \leq 4$, $1 \le i \le 5$.

Following your method of converting the equation into the nonnegative integers, we let $x_i = p_i - 1$, $1 \le i \le 5$.  Then each $x_i$ is a nonnegative integer.  Substituting $x_i + 1$ for $p_i$, $1 \le i \le 5$, in equation $1$ and simplifying yields
$$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 = 9 \tag{2}$$
which is an equation in the nonnegative integers subject to the restrictions that $x_i = p_i - 1 \leq 4 - 1 = 3$, $1 \leq i \leq 4$.

If we temporarily ignore the restrictions, equation $2$ has
$$\binom{9 + 5 - 1}{5 - 1} = \binom{13}{4}$$
solutions in the nonnegative integers.

From these, we must subtract those cases in which one or more of the $x_i$s exceeds $3$.  Since the $x_i$s are nonnegative integers, at most two variables can exceed $3$ since $3 \cdot 4 = 12 > 9$.

There are five ways to choose a variable that exceeds $3$.  Suppose it is $x_1$.  Then $x_1 \geq 4$.  Let $x_1' = x_1 - 4$.  Then $x_1'$ is a nonnegative integer.  Substituting $x_1' + 4$ for $x_1$ in equation $2$ and simplifying yields
$$x_1' + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 = 5 \tag{3}$$
which is an equation in the nonnegative integers with
$$\binom{5 + 5 - 1}{5 - 1} = \binom{9}{4}$$
solutions.  Therefore, there are
$$\binom{5}{1}\binom{9}{4}$$
solutions in which a variable exceeds $3$.

However, if we subtract this amount from the total, we will have subtracted too much.  This is because we will have subtracted each case in which two of the variables exceed $3$ twice, once for each way we could have designated one of the variables as the variable that exceeds $3$.  We only want to subtract such cases once, so we must add them to the total.

There are $\binom{5}{2}$ ways to select two of the five variables to exceed $3$.  Suppose they are $x_1$ and $x_2$.  Then $x_1 \geq 4$ and $x_2 \geq 4$.  Let $x_1' = x_1 - 4$ and $x_2' = x_2 - 4$.  Then $x_1'$ and $x_2'$ are nonnegative integers.  Substituting $x_1' + 4$ for $x_1$ and $x_2' + 4$ for $x_2$ in equation $2$ and simplifying yields
$$x_1' + x_2' + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 = 1 \tag{4}$$
which is an equation in the nonnegative integers with five solutions.  Hence, there are
$$\binom{5}{2}\binom{1 + 5 - 1}{5 - 1} = \binom{5}{2}\binom{5}{4}$$
solutions in which two variables exceed $3$.

By the [Inclusion-Exclusion Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle), the number of ways the professor can distribute the points to the five questions so that each question is worth a positive integer number of points that is at most $4$ is
$$\binom{13}{4} - \binom{5}{1}\binom{9}{4} + \binom{5}{2}\binom{5}{4}$$

Comment: If I understood you correctly, you meant to say, when we make sure one x exceeds 3, there will be combinations where another x can exceed 3. And if I then remove a case where two x's can exceed 3 then I will have subtracted this case twice from the total. Right? But my questions is if we subtract C(5,4)C(5,2) from C(9,4)C(5,1), what happens to the cases where two x's can exceed 3, because we still want to get rid of the combinations when two x's exceed 3 from the total after all?

Comment: You understood what I said correctly.  When we subtract those cases in which an $x_i$ exceeds $3$, we subtract those cases in which two $x_i$s exceed $3$ twice.  We only want to subtract those cases once, which is why we need to add the $\binom{5}{2}\binom{5}{4}$ cases in which two $x_i$s exceed $3$ to the total so that we only subtract them once.

Comment: Here is a toy example:  Suppose we wish to find the number of nonnegative integer solutions of the equation $x_1 + x_2 = 8$ in which $x_1, x_2 \leq 3$.  The equation has nine solutions, none of which satisfy the restrictions: $(0, 8), (1, 7), (2, 6), (3, 5), (4, 4), (5, 3), (6, 2), (7, 1), (8, 0)$.  Of these, five violate the restriction that $x_1 \leq 3$: They are $(4, 4), (5, 3), (6, 2), (7, 1), (8, 0)$.   Five solutions violate the restriction that $x_2 \leq 3$: They are:  $(0, 8), (1, 7), (2, 6), (3, 5), (4, 4)$.

Comment: If we subtract those solutions that violate one of the restrictions from the total, we get $9 - 2 \cdot 5 = -1$ solutions.  This is because we subtracted the solution $(4, 4)$ twice.  We subtracted it twice since it violates both the restrictions.  However, we only want to subtract it once, so we must add that case to the total, which gives $9 - 2 \cdot 5 + 1 = 0$ solutions that satisfy the two restrictions.

Comment: back to your second reply, you said "we subtract those cases in which two  $x_i$ exceed 3 twice". I thought I understood but actually I didn't. If we're to guarantee that one x, lets say $x_1$ has more than 3. Then there'll be cases where $x_2$ or $ x_3$ etc.. can exceed 3? But since there're 5 ways of guaranteeing which $ x_i$ should exceed 3, we'll in total have 5 ways where the other x's also exceed 4. This means that we'd have counted it 4 too many times when we remove it from the total so shouldn't we add it 4 times instead of just once? I'm a bit confused.

Comment: You will notice that I subtracted the number of cases in which a particular variable exceeds $4$ in my answer, then multiplied by the five ways of selecting that variable. The problem with doing that is that we subtract each case when two particular variables exceed $4$ twice. Thus, there are $5 \cdot 2=10$ cases in which two variables exceed $4$, each of which get subtracted twice. We only want to subtract them once, so we add them back. There are $\binom{5}{2}=10$ ways of selecting the two variables that exceed $4$. We multiply that number by the number of ways two variables can exceed $4$.

Comment: The thing I don't understand is the twice part tho. When you choose your $x_i$ so that it exceed 3, you will have multiple ways where other $x_i$s can also exceed 3 right? Where did the twice part come from? Because from what I understood, when we multiply C(9,4) by 5 we have different types of other combinations where a different $x_i$ is guaranteed to exceed 3 and the others will be distributed randomly.

Comment: If the variables $x_i$ and $x_j$ both exceed $4$, you subtract them twice because you subtract them once when you subtract those cases in which $x_i > 4$ and once when you subtract those cases in which $x_j > 4$.

Comment: I feel stupid for not understanding, since principle of inclusion and exclusion is about sets. Could maybe explain it by using set theory. I mean I know that this [∣A∪B∣=∣A∣+∣B∣−∣A∩B∣] is what is happening in your solution but I just can't put two and two together. So A {Combinations when one x can exceed 3}, B={Number of ways two x's can exceed 3}, so AUB = {Combinations when one and two x's exceed 3}. But what does A∩B mean? I feel like all the combinations we need are already in set A, so why do we even need B? Thanks for the help

Comment: I mean what type of combinations are in set B that is not already present in set A

Comment: If $A_i$ is the set of outcomes in which $x_i$ exceeds $4$ and $A_j$ is the set of outcomes in which $x_j$ exceeds $4$, then $A_i \cap A_j$ is the set of outcomes in which both $x_i$ and $x_j$ exceed $4$.  For instance, $(7, 2, 3, 0, 2)$ is an outcome in which $x_1$ exceeds $4$, but $x_2$ does not; $(3, 5, 2, 4, 2)$ is an outcome in which $x_2$ exceeds $4$, but $x_1$ does not; and $(5, 6, 1, 2, 0)$ is an outcome in which both $x_1$ and $x_2$ exceed $3$.

Comment: Omg I think it finally made sense to me. Just to make sure tho, I will explain to you what I think you meant. We have 9 points to distribute to 5 x's. When $x_1$ exceeds 3 we can have a combination (4, 4,1,0,0) and when $x_2$ exceeds 3 we can also have a combination (4,4,1,0,0). So one example of $ A_i ∩ A_j $ is then (4,4,1,0,0)? If we had removed C(9,4)*5 from the total we would have removed for example (4,4,1,0,0) twice and thus we need to add this combination (4,4,1,0,0) one time with the help of C(5,2)*C(5,4). Did I get it right this time?

Comment: Yes, you explained it well.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help, I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

Our generating function is

$\begin {align*}
f(x)&=\left ( x+x^2+x^3+x^4 \right )^5\\&=x^5\left ( \frac{1-x^4}{1-x} \right )^5
\end{align*}$

So the answer is

$\begin {align*}
[x^{14}]f(x)&=[x^9]\left ( 1-5x^4+10x^8-h(x) \right )\sum_{k=0}^{\infty }\binom{-5}{k}(-x)^k\\&=\left ( [x^9]-5[x^5]+10[x] \right )\binom{k+4}{4}\\&=\binom{13}{4}-5\binom{9}{4}+10\binom{5}{4}\\&=\boldsymbol {135}
\end{align*}$

Answer (score 1):

If you are using stars and bars, be alert to a way to reduce/eliminate inclusion-exclusion.

Here I transform the problem as $5$ boxes (ie $4$ bars) with $4$ marks each from which I can **withdraw** zero to three marks (corresponding to giving $4-1$ marks) from any box and I need to withdraw a total of $6$ marks.

*Note that now only one box can violate restrictions.*

Then by stars and bars it becomes

$$\binom{4+4}{4} -\binom51\binom{2+4}4=135$$

Comment: An elegant solution.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig: Thanks for your kind comment !